# How to set Azure webapp default document to sub directory endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I deployed a webapi to an Azure webapp. I would like the default document to be the Swagger Index.html. From AzureCLI I updated the default document

`az webapp update  -g [resourceGroup] -n [appname] --add siteConfig.defaultDocuments swagger\index.html`

and verified it was updated from in the portat but `az webapp show` indicates the defaultDocuments value is null.

Any ideas on how to set the default document and why there is a difference from the portal and Azure Cli?

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing the same from my end, this was working fine when I tried refreshing the default Documents page and then using the `az webapp show` command.

Update Command

```
az webapp update -g <YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP> -n <YOUR_WEBAPP_NAME> --add siteConfig.defaultDocuments index1ed.html
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]

show command after refresh

```
az webapp show --name <YOUR_WEBAPP_NAME> --resource-group <YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP>
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Mine still shows null after the refresh however it seems to have commited successfully because the behavior and portal interface. 

I have created another webapp and it doesn't seem to have the issue. It updates and shows the default document after running the show subcommand.

Seems like a caching issue on the server. Is there a command to refresh the cache?